# ReferenceError: message is not defined, please resolve this

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to javascript as well have discord js, i am getting an error when running my discord bot, here, Also please fix the code and tell me what i did wrong, thankyou.

I have been making a all feature discord bot, and this is the first error i have found which i am unable to fix, i'd appreciate it greatly if any of you could help.

```js
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
```

> ReferenceError: message is not defined

```js
// Constant Variables
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const prefix = "!";
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Startup 1 Below Listener Events
client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Countless Is Up And Running, Wooohooo");
});

// Moderation 2 Below
client.on("Message", (Message) => {
  if (Message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS"])) {
    //console.log(message.content);

    if (Message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {
      //message.channel.send("Kick")

      let member = Message.mentions.members.first();
      member.kick().then((member) => {
        Message.channel.send(
          "https://gph.is/2iBA79h :wave: " +
            member.displayName +
            " has been kicked!"
        );
      });
    }
  }
});

client.on("Message", (Message) => {
  if (Message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) {
    //console.log(message.content);

    if (Message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {
      //message.channel.send("Ban")

      let member = Message.mentions.members.first();
      member.ban().then((member) => {
        Message.channel.send(
          "https://gph.is/29507Ei :wave: " +
            member.displayName +
            " has been banned!"
        );
      });
    }
  }
});

// Variables
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

// Return Statements
if (Message.author.bot) return; // Ignores All Bots
if (!Message.content.startWith(prefix)) return; // Returns Messages if doesnt start with the prefix

// Command Handler
try {
  // Bonus: Auto-Reload ()
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${cmd}.js`)];

  let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
  commandFile.run(client, Message, args);
} catch (e) {
  // Will catch any errors within code or commands
  console.log(e.stack);
}

client.login(token);
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; at that point in your code, `message` is not defined anywhere. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: I watched this video, as i said i am new to javascript and discordjs.
how would i define it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ygc04PcjoLk&t=223s

Comment: Is this a typo? JavaScript is case-sensitive, and your code is using `Message` everywhere except in the line with the error (and in some comments....) Should the line with the error be `let args = Message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');` instead?

Comment: Still doesnt work

Comment: Well, `Message` still needs to be *defined* so you probably want to move the code into the scope which has `Message` defined. I.e. `client.on('Message', Message => {... let args = Message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' '); }`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

```
clinet.on("message", Message => {});
```

In the following you defined message parameter with a capital "M".

So you need to mention the Message with a capital M.

Here's the fix for args V

```
let args = Message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
```

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. You've got `message` on one line and `Message` on another. JavaScript variables are case-sensitive. You also can't have `message` defined outside of a scope *`client.on()` in this case*. I recommend putting everything that requires messages into your `client.on('Message', Message => {}` scope.

You should probably use only one scope too.

Comment: Venk, please add me on discord i'd like some more help with this. (if you can)

Gelvey.#0001

Comment: Just move everything that isn't in a scope into the `Client.On('message') {}`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to keep the "args" var inside a client.on callback.

Like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
     let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
})
```